# Turn SQL query into ActiveRecord/Arel query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I have a SQL query

```
SELECT 
  events.id
FROM
 events
   JOIN flows ON flows.event_id=events.id
   JOIN prices ON prices.priceable_id=flows.id AND prices.priceable_type='Flow'
GROUP BY
  events.id
HAVING SUM(prices.inclusive_tax)>200;
```

that is working as expected.

I have turned it into a query:

```
Event.select('events.id').joins(:flows => :price).group('events.id').having('SUM(prices.inclusive_tax) > 200')
```

but I get ids. Is it possible to turn it into an ActiveRecord/Arel query so I get `events` records instead?

Comment: Possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `Event.select('events.id').joins(:flows => :price).group('events.id').having('SUM(prices.inclusive_tax) > 200')` returns `ids` just fine. Could I have records instead? :)

Comment: Use `Event.select('*').....` or `Event.select('events.*').....` instead of `Event.select('events.id').....`, it's allow you to get all column from table not only `id`.

Comment: This fails with `Column 'events.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` .

Comment: add a chain of select `Event.select('events.id', 'events.title', 'events.name')` etc, `id` should be first in select method, to return records instead you should tell `select` get not only `events.id`.

Comment: OK. that worked with a group clause: `Event.select('events.id, events.value_date, events.transaction_id, events.type, events.uri, events.instrument_id').group('events.id, events.value_date, events.transaction_id, events.type, events.uri, events.instrument_id').joins(:flows => :price).having('SUM(prices.inclusive_tax) > 200')` but it feels hacky. any way to specify "all attributes" without specifying by hand?

Comment: Instead of an expression, `*` can be written in the output list as a shorthand for all the columns of the selected rows. Also, you can write `table_name.*` as a shorthand for the columns coming from just that table.

Comment: Yes but it fails `Event.select("*").group("*").joins(:flows => :price).having('SUM(prices.inclusive_tax) > 200')` yields Incorrect syntax near '*'. Same with `events.*`.

Comment: i assume, you have a wrong `group(*)`, it should contain `id` or `events.id` or column for group. All of its very simple and good described in the documentation. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html 
Read it.

Comment: `Event.select("*").group("events.id").joins(:flows => :price).having('SUM(prices.inclusive_tax) > 200')` also yields an error (`Column 'events.value_date' is invalid in the select list`).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm not using postgresql. I'll try to find the same for SQL Azure. Thanks for all the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try modifying your query to the format below. It is what I typically use for reports

```
Event.find(:all, :conditions => condition_text, :from => from_text, :select => select_text, :joins => join_text)
```